# Cognito integration into React Website causes blank page and Uncaught Error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito

I am trying to integrate Cognito authentication which is causing a blank page and the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Both UserPoolId and ClientId are required.
    CognitoUserPool CognitoUserPool.js:35
    js UserPool.js:9
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 15
```

I created a `UserPool.js` file that contains the following:

```
import { CognitoUserPool } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
const poolData = {

    UserPoolID: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL,
    ClientId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_CLIENT,
} 
export default new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
```

I'm testing user account creation, so I imported it into my Register.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import UserPool from "../UserPool";

export const Register = () => {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    password2: "",
  });
  //submit data to the backend
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      UserPool.Register(userData)

      if (userData.name && userData.email && userData.password) {
        if (userData.terms) {
          if (userData.password === userData.password2) {
            axios
              .post(`www.url.com`, userData)
              .then((res) => {
                redirectToCompleted();
              })
```

I've tried without referencing the environment variables in the `UserPool.js`, but that gave me the same error as above. I also added `import UserPool from "../UserPool";` in `app.js`, but that gives me a `'UserPool' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars` and `'pool_region' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars` warnings.

So I'm unsure what I'm missing. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing ClientId incorrectly to Cognito. The [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js) and the error message are both suggesting to use `ClientId` instead of `userPoolWebClientId`

So instead of this

```
const poolData = {

    UserPoolID: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_CLIENT,
}
```

try this:

```
const poolData = {

    UserPoolID: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL,
    ClientId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_CLIENT,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I forgot to mention that I originally had ClientId. It still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple....

`UserPoolId` instead of `UserPoolID`